# p4 integrate/merge between depots

Tags: perforce

We have a dev depot

> //dev/main/mytool

and production depot

> //prod/9.3.4/app/mytool

How do I integrate/merge all the new changesets in dev to production ?

I tried the [following](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/superuser.remote_depots.code_drops.html):

```
p4 client dev_port
View:
//prod/9.3.4/app/mytool/... //dev_port/...
p4 integrate //dev/main/mytool/... //prod/9.3.4/app/mytool/...
```

This creates a big 'default' changeset with lot of files, but no diff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p4 integrate //dev/main/mytool/... //prod/9.3.4/app/mytool/...
p4 resolve -as
p4 resolve
```

`p4 integrate` opens the files and schedules resolves (merges or other propagation of change from the source to the target).

`p4 resolve` does the job of actually applying the changes.  You can pick when you `resolve` whether you want to do a "safe merge" (i.e. a merge based on a whole-file diff), an "automatic merge" (i.e. allowing textual line-level merges), or to automatically overwrite the target with the source, or ignore the source, or make manual adjustments.  The above sequence starts with a "safe merge" and then does the rest in interactive mode.

Comment: Ah !! Missed that. Thanks. And to choose range of changesets, how do I specify that ?

Comment: That's done when you run the `integrate` (integrate decides which changes to apply and which files to apply them to, resolve decides how to apply them).  `p4 integrate //dev/main/mytool/...@123,234 //prod/9.3.4/app/mytool/...`