# Perforce: The submitted file doesn't match workspace version

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I am facing a weird behavior in `perforce` submitted files, after `p4 integrate`

**Scenario**

Repo contains `C#` code and the built `DLL`. I wished to integrate a changeset from one branch to another
so I am following the steps which I had [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53768209/p4-integrate-merge-between-depots), a while ago

The `.cs` files doesn't complain. If there is resolve conflict in the `DLL`, I choose either of `Accept Source` or `Accept Target` without much care. Reason being, I always rebuild the `DLL` before submitting

**Issue**

The `DLL` which was built in local workspace and reflected in the changeset is correct. I tested it locally and do `p4 submit`. But to my amazement, the `DLL` submitted is not the one which I had built. Instead the one which came from that other branch was submitted

**Confusion**

I thought that with `perforce`, when a file is opened in a changeset, always the latest(local) copy will be submitted. That is why I don't pay much attention if there are conflict reported in `DLL`

Isn't that correct ?

Why would the submitted file be different from my workspace version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "accept source" you're recording that you want the target file to be an exact copy of the source file; consequently, if you submit the file, it's not even transferred from the workspace (in order to save time) -- instead it's just copied server-side.  If you tampered with the workspace file, this leads to the situation you describe where the workspace is now inconsistent with the depot, just like if you'd modified a file that wasn't open for edit.

If you submit with the `-t` flag (for "tamper checking"), it will check for tampered files by comparing what's in your workspace with what **should** be in your workspace according to the resolve options you picked:

```
C:\Perforce\test\integ>p4 integ source target
//depot/integ/target#2 - integrate from //depot/integ/source#3

C:\Perforce\test\integ>p4 resolve -at
c:\Perforce\test\integ\target - vs //depot/integ/source#3
//Samwise-dvcs-1509687817/integ/target - copy from //depot/integ/source

C:\Perforce\test\integ>echo tampertampertamper >> target

C:\Perforce\test\integ>p4 submit -t -d "submitting tampered file"
Submitting change 190.
Locking 1 files ...
integrate //depot/integ/target#3
//Samwise-dvcs-1509687817/integ/target tampered with after resolve - edit or revert.
Submit aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 190'.
Some file(s) could not be transferred from client.
```

If you `p4 edit` the file, it's changed from a pure `copy` to an `edit`, and will be read from the workspace instead of from the source file:

```
C:\Perforce\test\integ>p4 edit target
//depot/integ/target#2 - reopened for edit

C:\Perforce\test\integ>p4 submit -c 190
Submitting change 190.
edit //depot/integ/target#3
Change 190 submitted.
```

Comment: Thanx for that explanation. Does that mean my workflow show edit the file after integrate/resolve as I'll be doing a rebuild ? And neither `Accept theirs/yours` will work. I did observe tampering error from the command line. But never observed that error from P4V GUI. The 'Tamper Checking' https://community.perforce.com/s/article/1027 link says it's always on and can't be disabled, so the changed file in local workspace should have raised error ? I can't locate `-t` flag in `submit`. I am using perforce on windows

Comment: Yes, you should open for edit (I think "check out" in P4V?) if you want to make local changes.  Alternatively, exclude this file from the merge operation entirely (set it to "isolate" in the stream spec, or remove it from the branch view) since it's not something that you're actually merging/copying.

Comment: And about the `-t` option ? I can't locate any such option in `p4 submit`

Comment: See `p4 help undoc` -- it's not a standard option because it slows large branch/copy operations down if submit has to check every file to make sure you didn't modify it.  Normally only `merge`d files are tamper-checked (they're a less common case and the cost of messing them up is higher since it messes up the actual history in the depot rather than just leaving one workspace in an inconsistent state).

Comment: The perforce community link which I shared showed tampering check with integrate, as default. Maybe `P4V` GUI not doing it. Will check. Thanks

Comment: Look at the release notes quoted in that article: `Tamper checking for branch/sync files and resolve 'at' files is not done at submit time, but 'p4 diff -sb' will report those files.`  "Accept source" in P4V is the same as `resolve 'at'`.